# How make it works a function on a single header in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJs, and i want to use a single header over all my pages. For the pages, i'm using ng-route. Right now, i want to make a test for the logout button (which lives in the header), but is not working. This is my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adminApp">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin Test</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="app/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <base href="/">

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-include="'app/components/include/header.html'"></div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/login/admin-login.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/admin-home.js"></script>
<script src="app/routes/admin-route.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my html for my header

```
<section class="admin-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a id="admin-logo"><img src="myimagesource" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" id="login" align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-user" ng-click="logout()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My code for the header:

```
(function(){

    var head = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/include/header.html',
        controller: headCtrl
    };

    angular
        .module('adminApp')
        .component('adminHead', head);
        headCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
        function headCtrl($scope){

            $scope.logout = function(){
                console.log('Success');
            }

        }

})();
```

The `adminHead` on the component comes from my route file:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('adminApp')
        .config(config);
        config.$inject = ["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider"];
        function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

            $routeProvider

                .when('/', {
                    template: '<admin-login></admin-login>'
                })

                .when('/head', {
                    template: '<admin-head></admin-head>'
                })

                .when('/home', {
                    template: '<admin-home></admin-home>'
                })                

                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }

})();
```

When i click on the logout button, nothing happens. Someone can guide me please? What can i do to make the function(s) work no matter the page i'm in (login or home)? Something's missing?

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript, and Bootstrap for the HTML.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either ng-include or component for reusability in the above example. So remove the element 
**`"<div ng-include="'app/components/include/header.html'"></div>"`** and  add **`<admin-head></admin-head>`** try again. Here components can be called by using element alone.

If you want to use both then try to include the component `**"<admin-head></admin-head>"**` in the header.html and have the component as separate html..